# Python Construct - consume data for optional field

Tags: python, construct

With the Python [construct](http://construct.wikispaces.com/) library, the data I'm parsing has a field which only has meaning if a flag is set.

However, the data field is always present.

Therefore, I would like to consume the data in any case, but only set the field value based on the flag's value.

For example, if the structure is (incorrectly) defined as:

```
struct = Struct("struct",
    Flag("flag"),
    UBInt8("optional_data"),
    UBInt8("mandatory")
)
```

For the data:

```
>>> struct.parse("010203".decode("hex"))
```

The result should be:

```
Container({'flag': True, 'mandatory': 3, 'optional_data': 2})
```

And for data:

```
>>> struct.parse("000203".decode("hex"))
```

The desired result is:

```
Container({'flag': False, 'mandatory': 3, 'optional_data': None})
```

I have tried the following:

```
struct = Struct("struct",
    Flag("flag"),
    IfThenElse("optional_data", lambda ctx: ctx.flag,
        UBInt8("dummy"),
        Padding(1)
    ),
    UBInt8("mandatory")
)
```

However, Padding() puts the raw data in the field, like so:

```
>>> struct.parse("000203".decode("hex"))
Container({'flag': False, 'mandatory': 3, 'optional_data': '\x02'})
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand your problem correctly. If your problem is only that the padding is not parsed as int, then you dont need the IFThenElse. You can check the parsed container in your code for flag and choose to ignore the optional_data field.

```
struct = Struct("struct",
    Flag("flag"),
    UBInt8("optional_data"),
    UBInt8("mandatory")
)
```

If your problem is that you want the name Optional Data to be used only when the flag is set but the name dummy to be used when flag is not set, then you need to define two Ifs

```
struct = Struct("struct",
    Flag("flag"),
    If("optional_data", lambda ctx: ctx.flag,
        UBInt8("useful_byte"),
    ),
    If("dummy", lambda ctx: !ctx.flag,
        UBInt8("ignore_byte"),
    ),
    UBInt8("mandatory")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use an Adapter similar to the LengthValueAdapter for a Sequence

```
class LengthValueAdapter(Adapter):
"""
Adapter for length-value pairs. It extracts only the value from the 
pair, and calculates the length based on the value.
See PrefixedArray and PascalString.

Parameters:
* subcon - the subcon returning a length-value pair
"""
__slots__ = []
def _encode(self, obj, context):
    return (len(obj), obj)
def _decode(self, obj, context):
    return obj[1]

class OptionalDataAdapter(Adapter):
__slots__ = []
def _decode(self, obj, context):
  if context.flag:
    return obj
  else
    return None
```

So

```
struct = Struct("struct",
    Flag("flag"),
    OptionalDataAdapter(UBInt8("optional_data")),
    UBInt8("mandatory")
)
```